# Deprecated : strpos(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2rock\app\\\list.phtml on line 112

Tags: magento2.4

when i install a free template
i try to create a catagory
I end up with an error that looks like this

Exception #0 (Exception): Deprecated Functionality: strpos(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\mage2rock\app\design\frontend\Hidden\apparel\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml on line 112

```
<div class="product-item-inner">
                                <div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                    <div class="actions-primary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs due to `PHP8.1`, You need to handle the `strpos` function in the `list.phtml` file.

**Update your code using below :-**

Class `product-item-actions`

```
<?= ($pos && strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions')) ? $position : '' ?>
```

Class `actions-primary`

```
<?= ($pos && strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary')) ? $position : '' ?>
```

Class `actions-secondary`

```
<?= ($pos && strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary')) ? $position : '' ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the error by adding if condition for checking variable is null or not, see the below example

```
<?= if ($pos && strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary')) :
```

first, check whether the variable $pos is null or not. if it is not null then pass into strpos() function. you can replace the $pos variable with your actual variable.

Answer (score 0):

this indicates that you are using the strpos function in PHP with a parameter that is `null`.

In PHP, strpos is used to find the position of a substring within a string. However, it expects the first parameter (the string to search within) to be a string, not `null`.

To resolve this issue, you should ensure that the variable you are passing to strpos is a valid string. You can do this by checking if the variable is `null` before calling strpos. For example:

```
if ($yourVariable !== null) {
    $position = strpos($yourVariable, $needle);
    // Rest of your code that uses $position
} else {
    // Handle the case where $yourVariable is null
}
```

OR

```
strpos($yourVariable ?? "",needle)
```